# Moment generating function of two variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, moment-generating-functions

[image]

I am able to do all the parts except the very last. I have been trying to coax the differential equation $\frac{M'}{M}=t$ or something to that effect but I don't see how I can achieve this. **Hints** would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $M(2t)=M(t)^3 M(-t)$ and $M(t)=M(-t)$, so $M(2t)=M(t)^4$.
Hence we have a functional equation for $m(t)=t^{-2}\log M(t)$ (let $m(0)=\frac12s^2=\frac12$):
$$m(2t)=m(t)\quad\text{for all }t\tag{1}$$
But we know
$$
m(t)=\frac12+o(1)\text{ for small }t\tag{2}
$$
from the expansion of $M(t)$.

Now equations (1) and (2) together implies $m$ is constant $\frac12$.  Can you see why?

Comment: So letting $o(1) = f_1(t)$ we can see that $f_1(t)=f_1(2t) \implies f$ constant and $m(0) = 1/2$ gives the result? Question: how did we get equation (2)

Comment: Not quite.  By (1), $m(t)=m(t/2)=m(t/4)=\dots$.  By (2), we have $m(t/2^n)\to\frac12$.  The only way to reconcile these two is if $m(t)=\frac12$, any other value would violate the limit.

Comment: oh yes of course